# Index 6 out of bounds for length 6

Tags: java, рекурсия

Суть в том, чтобы сделать программу которая считает единицы в числе. А когда видит `2` нуля, то заканчивает свою работу. Обязательные условия. Сделать с помощью рекурсии, без глобальных переменных. Вроде как сделал, но выдает ошибку

> Index 6 out of bounds for length 6

Как бороться, не знаю...

```
import java.lang.*;

public class solution {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        recursion(111001);
    }

    public static int recursion(int numbers){
        String temp = Integer.toString(numbers);
        int[] newGuess = new int[temp.length()];
        int counter = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < temp.length(); i++)
        {
            newGuess[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        if(newGuess[i] + newGuess[i+1] == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(newGuess[i] + 0 == 1){
            counter += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        return recursion(numbers);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что вернет `newGuess[i+1]`, когда `i` равен `temp.length() - 1`?

Что вернет `newGuess[i]`, когда `i` равен `temp.length()`?

Зачем тут рекурсия, и когда она остановится, если в числе нет двух нулей подряд?

Comment: Человеку домашку завтра сдавать, а ты вместо того, чтобы написать как надо, ёрничаешь.

Comment: Ну зачем рекурсия вроде описано в вопросе. Видимо по ТЗ.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/518739)

Comment: @AlexSazonov - является ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

вы не совсем понимаете как должна работать рекурсия.

1. Вы решаете задачу не совсем верно. В вашей функции, вы проверяете только первые две цифры, ваш параметр i при заходе в функцию всегда равен 0, вы нигде его не изменяете. То же самое с counter.
2. Вам стоит ввести параметр количества цифр оставшегося числа и запускать рекурсию от него.
3. У вас нет выхода из рекурсии, если в числе нет двух нулей подряд.
4. newGuess[i] + 0 == 1 - просто странно прибавлять ноль
5. Длину строки/саму строку вы также не меняете.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что у вас есть в цикле такая вот запись:

```
newGuess[i+1]
```

Когда вы приходите на последнюю итерацию цикла то вы обращаетесь к несуществующему элементу. К примеру если в цикле 3 элемента, то будет 3 итерации и на 3ей ваш `i+1` будет равен индексу 3, которого не существует.

Решить это можно двумя способами (тут надо по задаче смотреть). Либо просто не доходить до последнего элемента

```
for (; i < temp.length() - 1; i++) {}
```

Или, если вам нужен этот последний элемент, то проверять, что если элемент последний то выполнять какое-то другое действие

```
for (; i < temp.length() - 1; i++) {
    // some code
    if (i == temp.length() - 1) {
        // обработать последний элемент
    }
}
```